# Shifting ArcMap shapefile (lines) from point A to point B?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, cartography

I would like to shift a shapefile (made of lines) from one point to another; not far away. This is really just for a cartographic adjustment, not a survey-level correction.

I was going to use Rubbersheeting but don't want to risk stretching the .shp; I only want to move it a bit.

I am just past a beginner level ArcGIS user.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details about what you've tried, and what happens (or doesn't happen) when you try it.

Comment: Thanks, Midavalo, I was going to try rubbersheeting it but don't want to stretch it, merely move it. I see options for shifting a raster file from place to place but not for a .shp that is all lines. BTW, I would say that my knowledge level for ArcGIS is probably just past entry level.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Rasters, Vector layers can be edited easily within ArcMap, so you could just edit your shapefile, select the features you want to move, and just drag them to the new position.

First take a copy of your shapefile (for backup in case something goes awry!).  In ArcMap open the Catalog window, browse to your shapefile, right-click > Copy, then right-click > Paste into the same folder.

In ArcMap, turn on the Editor toolbar:

[image]

From the Editor toolbar, click Edit > Start Editing

[image]

Select the features you wish to move (the default Edit tool that activates when you start editing will allow you to draw a selection box)

[image]

Now just drag and drop your selected features to their new location.

[image]

Once you are happy with their position select Edit > Save Edits and Edit > Stop Editing to save your changes.

[image]

Comment: ! Thank you! I was "projecting" way too much into the problem.